# How can I implement service-to-service authentication with Office365 using the OAuth2 and Mailkit mechanism in Console Application?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, office365, mailkit

Here I want to read E-mail using Office365, Oauth2 in Console Application.

I am Getting Authentication Failed error

**Here Account is getting NULL after retrieving authToken.**

[image]

**Below is my App Registration**

[image]

I wrote code with both way PublicClientApplicationBuilder and confidentialClientApplication

**Below is code with PublicClientApplicationBuilder**
[image]

**Below code with ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder - Microsoft.Graph Scope**

**Here I tried with Outlook.office365.com as a scope as well.**

[image]

I also tried with ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder - Outlook Office365 Scope

```
string[] scopesCon = new string[] {  "https://outlook.office365.com/.default"};
```

***Please Let me know what I am missing to make work - to authenticate mailbox to read mails***

**Update Note - This code successfully works
I Passed mail server as a username from we are reading emails. SaslMechanismOAuth2(authToken.Account.UserName, AccessToken)**

Comment: You need to get a token.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @jdweng Toekn I am already getting . Authentication is getting fail. And Account is populating as NULL

Comment: I would start by trying to connect with a browser manually to see if you can connected.  Try deleting cookies.  If it still fails it may be OS or Net/Core version be old and not supporting the encryption mode.  Error may just be an expired token.

Comment: @MitJacob You can also use **MS Graph** query to list messages in the mailbox. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet?context=outlook%2Fcontext&tabs=aad&tutorial-step=5).

Comment: @jdweng What i have to pass in authToken.Account.UserName? SaslMechanismOAuth2(authToken.Account.UserName, AccessToken)

Comment: @Sridevi Here do you have idea what value for authToken.Account.UserName? In SaslMechanismOAuth2(authToken.Account.UserName, AccessToken).

Comment: Its Authenticated now. Able to read Inbox. Thank you @Sridevi

Comment: Finally it works. I passed mailserver name like test_support@domain.com = authToke.Account.USerName .......SaslMechanismOAuth2(authToken.Account.UserName, AccessToken). This code is successfully works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of below **Microsoft Graph API** query to read emails of specific user.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/username@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders/inbox/messages
```

I registered one Azure AD application and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Now, I generated one **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:<appID>
grant_type:client_credentials
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used above access token to run Graph API query, I got list of emails successfully in **response** like below:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/username@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders/inbox/messages
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

To run same **Microsoft Graph** query in c#, you can make use of below sample  code:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace GraphApp
{
    class MSGraph
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            var tenantId = "tenantID";
            var clientId = "appID";
            var clientSecret = "secret";
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
            var inbox = await graphClient.Users["userID"].MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages.GetAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**Reference:**
[Build .NET apps with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet?context=outlook%2Fcontext&tabs=aad&tutorial-step=5)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I implemented Graph PAI to read email. How can I add Filter to get only unread email List

Comment: To get only **unread** email list, you can use this query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/username@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=isRead+eq+false&$select=subject,sender`

Comment: What is difference between Microsoft.Graph API and Microsoft.Outlook API. Initially I implemented code with Putlook365 API.  So asking what is difference?